# anaconda - path environment variable in windows

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, anaconda

I am trying to run python from the windows command prompt (windows 10). So the result is the typical one when the path environment variable is not configured

```
 c:\windows\system32>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
 program or batch file
```

however, I am not sure which is the right directory I should set up in the path variable.

I tried a few variations, and none of them work, including:

```
c:\users\xxx\anaconda3
c:\users\xxx\anaconda3\Scripts
c:\users\xxx\anaconda3\libs\python34
```

and none of them works.

Does anyone have experience with this particular system constellation (windows, anaconda). Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

it turns out I was mistaken.

Solution is: in anaconda (as well as in other implementations), set the path environment variable to the directory where 'python.exe' is installed.

As a default, the python.exe file in anaconda is in:

```
c:\.....\anaconda
```

after you do that, obviously, the python command works, in my case, yielding the following.

```
python
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.2.0. (64|bit)|(default, Nov 7 2015), etc, etc
```

Comment: For me on windows 8.1 with anaconda3 it was: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
I also wanted the activate and diactivate commands.

Comment: some times here `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3`

Answer (score 27):

Instead of giving the path following way:

```
C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
```

**Do this:**

```
C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\
```

Comment: In some cases (like mine) the path is just `C:\Users\[User_Name]\Anaconda3`.

Answer (score 13):

The default location for python.exe should be here: `c:\users\xxx\anaconda3`
One solution to find where it is, is to open the Anaconda Prompt then execute:

```
> where python
```

This will return the absolute path of locations of python eg:

```
(base) C:\>where python
C:\Users\Chad\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\python.exe
C:\dev\Python27\python.exe
C:\dev\Python34\python.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

C:\Users\\Anaconda3

I just added above path , to my path environment variables and it worked.
Now, all we have to do is to move to the .py script location directory, open the cmd with that location and run to see the output.

Answer (score 4):

You can also run `conda init` as below,

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda init cmd.exe
```

or

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda init powershell
```

Note that the execution policy of powershell must be set, e.g. using `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2
```

For me this was the default installation directory on Windows 7. Found it via [Rusy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320307/1242521)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, you may find it here:

`C:\Users\\[USER]\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\\[ENVIRONMENT]\python.exe`

or

`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Answer (score 3):

Try path env var for the system (on Windows)

`C:\ ...\Anaconda3\`

`C:\ ...\Anaconda3\scripts`

`C:\ ...\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

Must solve! It worked for me.

Comment: not working............

Answer (score 2):

To export the exact set of paths used by Anaconda, use the command `echo %PATH%` in Anaconda Prompt. This is needed to avoid problems with certain libraries such as SSL.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240362/663028

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention that in some win 10 systems, Microsoft pre-installed a python. Thus, in order to invoke the python installed in the anaconda, you should adjust the order of the environment variable to ensure that the anaconda has a higher priority.

[image: V]

Comment: You can delete the python.exe in the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps folder. It has 0 kb size and you can safely delete it. Then add c:\users\xxx\anaconda3 path to your path variable and it should work.

Comment: this was my issue as well. I just removed the whole `...\WindowsApps` entry. It is only muddying the path.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just re-install Anaconda, and tick the option add variable to Path.. This will prevent you from making mistakes when editing environment variables. If you make mistakes here, your operating system could start malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the **Directory/Folder path where python.exe is available** in Anaconda folder like

```
C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\
```

This should must work.