# Anaconda Installed but Cannot Launch Navigator

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

Anaconda (listed as "Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda 4.3.1 64 bit)" ) is in my programs and features list, but there is seeming **no Anaconda Navigator desktop app, as their seems to be no icon on my desktop and I am unable to search for it through "Start"**. Could this be because I have the 32-bit version of Anaconda downloaded and I have a 64-bit OS (I thought I should do this because Python on my computer was 64-bit) or because I downloaded Anaconda under "users" instead of Desktop. I also downloaded Anaconda twice, if that could be causing some of the problem. I have a Windows 10 laptop, if that is any help.

Comment: any error message you are getting?

Comment: i think you may have the path problem you should set path as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030373/anaconda-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: I am not getting an error message, I just don't know how I should go about launching the navigator.

Comment: From what I have seen online their should be a desktop app called Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: if you had successfully installed the anaconda the in windows 10 search bar you can type anaconda prompt to get the anaconda command line where you can start anaconda navigator by typing anaconda-navigator in anaconda prompt.

Comment: it is possible that you might be having some version of python installed separately prior to installing anaconda and that is why after installing anaconda icon is not showing up, you will have to uninstall anaconda(along the previous versions of python) and then start again

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 7.  The executable exists in the install directory, so I'm guessing it's related to the path environment variable.

Answer (score 32):

Try to

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
anaconda-navigator
```

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1580

Comment: The issue you mentioned refers to Linux, while OP stated they're using Windows. The command even has forward slashes that won't work on Windows. What makes you think your answer is relevant?

Comment: I was facing the same problem in MX linux. Tried everything and had to reinstall anaconda, but still didn't work until I found this solution. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your post! Could explain to a newbie why this works?

Answer (score 28):

Open up a command terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
and try running this command:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

When I installed Anaconda, and read the website docs, they said that they tend to not add a file or menu path to run the navigator because there are so many different versions of different systems, instead they give the above terminal command to start the navigator GUI and advise on setting up a shortcut to do this process manually - if that works for you it shouldn't be too much trouble to do it this way - I do it like this personally

Answer (score 22):

How I solved this issue:
1. Be connected to the internet.
2. Open the Anaconda Prompt (looks like a regular command window).
If you installed the .exe in your /name/user/ location you should be fine, if not navigate to it.
Then start an environment.

> conda info --envs

Then run

> conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator

Press y when prompted (if prompted). It will being downloading the packages needed.

Then run your newly installed Anaconda Navigator

> anaconda-navigator

It should start, and also appear in your regular windows 10 apps list.

Answer (score 11):

activate the virtual env with command:

```
 conda activate base
```

run anacond anavigator

```
 anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 5):

when you will type anaconda in windows 10 search bar it will give you the list as
[image]
then in terminal you have to type anaconda-navigator as
[image]
it will start anaconda on your machine.

Comment: Anaconda prompt is not showing up when I type it into my search bar. However, "Python 3.6.1 (Anaconda 4.4.0 32-bit)" is in my programs. Is Anaconda not fully installed?

Comment: Then anaconda is not successfully installed on your system.you can follow https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/windows to install anaconda on your windows.

Comment: I've followed the installation instructions through exactly, 3 times over, and at no stage has the anaconda-navigator command yielded any results (trying in Terminal, in Command Prompt, and in Anaconda Prompt); nor does anything containing 'anaconda' show up in my programs list or with a search. There is a directory though, at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3. Weirdly, on opening Anaconda Prompt I see this message: "'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command" ... any advice on that?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another option which worked in my case on **Windows 10**: Try uninstalling your previous installation, restart the system and run the installation again.
 Make sure you don't start any programs before installing Anaconda. You will find the installation finishes without prompting any kind of errors. 
Type in **Anaconda** in your Windows 10 Search bar. You will find **Anaconda Prompt** appear.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the reason as to why:

1-There seems to be no navigator icon

2-When conducting the above steps of running the "anaconda-navigator" command in prompt (whether cmd or Anaconda) it yields "anaconda navigator is not recognized as an internal or external command"

This was very frustrating to me as I'd installed the proper version multiple times with no avail.

**To solve this problem :**

- in the installation process, there will be an advanced options step with 2 selections one of which is unchecked (the top one). Make sure you check it which will add the navigator to the path of your machine variables.

Cheers,
Hossam

Comment: Yes! This is the only way the problem was solved here and Anaconda (either navigator or prompt) could be found!
I had never checked it before because of the "not recommended" thing and the text turns red when you check it!
But this is what worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it works :

```
export PATH=/home/yourUserName/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

after that run `anaconda-navigator` command. remember anaconda can't in Sudo mode, so don't use sudo at all.

[image: Conda Running Screenshot]

Comment: As per OP, he is facing issue in windows, and your answer is limited to Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on **Windows 10**. As soon as I cleared my Path variable from edit environment variables option, the icon started to appear. It was occurring because I had previously installed python 3.6.1 on my computer and added it to my path variable as C:\Python36;C:\Python36\DLL; and so on. **There isn't any need to uninstall Anaconda Navigator and start from scratch** if you have correctly followed the steps mentioned at the documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the system! You will be able to find the navigator once you restart the system after installation.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all solutions here but these 2 steps solved the issue:

1) manual update of open-ssl from here:
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2) update OpenSSL using `conda update openssl` command in the Anaconda Prompt

solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Miniconda first from [this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) link and later on download and install Anaconda. Then you will be able to see the navigator in your all programs list in the start menu. I hope this will help you. Let me know in case of any concerns.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling of these packages.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be in a anaconda environment

Below is a link how to activate the environment from the official documentation

On Windows, in your Anaconda Prompt, run `activate myenv`

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

And then run the anaconda navigator from the anaconda prompt by entering the command `anaconda-navigator`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today where only the prompt was available after installation.
Finally solved this by un-installing my regular python installation and then install anaconda(anaconda 3 v5.2.0, with python 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

I also have the issue on windows when i am unable to find the anaconda-navigator in start menu.
First you have to check **anaconda-navigator.exe** file in your anaconda folder if this file is present it means you have installed it properly otherwise there is some problem and you have to reinstall it.

Before reinstalling this points to be noticed 
1) You have to uninstall all previous python folder 
2) Check you environment variable and clear all previous python path

After this install anaconda
your problem will be resolved if not tell me the full error i will try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your Anaconda, delete the folder where it was. Then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

100% Solved. 
While Installing make sure you are connected to Internet. 
If already installed anaconda, open the anaconda command prompt and type following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
(internet connection is required)
```

Note: In some cases restarting may solve the issue of navigator.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

- Reinstall anacoda with ticked first check box
- **Remember to Restart**

Answer (score 0):

I have that error an the solution was to install the Win64 OpenSSL.

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case; it was available in the anaconda folder in "All App" from main menu

Answer (score 0):

**For people from Brazil**

There is a security software called **Warsaw** (used for home banking) ***that must be uninstalled!***  After you can install it back again.

After thousand times trying, installing, uninstalling, cleanning-up the regedit that finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**First Run This Command**

conda config --set auto_activate_base True

**Then Run This Command**

anaconda-navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your internet connection, then open your terminal and type `anaconda-navigator` or type `anaconda prompt` in the search bar and double click on the anaconda prompt.

If anaconda is opened, then you can turn on your Wi-Fi.

Comment: ...why would disconnecting from the Internet help? Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced with this issue. When I checked `conda --version` got a **command not recognized error**. Then I set the environmental variables as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61372328/13370201. After that run `anaconda navigator` command. Then it started to initializing anaconda navigator.[This](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows) tutorial also help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in Solus Baidge but I solved by activating the conda environment.

First activate

```
conda activate
```

Then run the navigator

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Make sure to run the installer as admin

In my case (Windows 11) it was a permission problem. Make sure to run the installer as `administrator`. You can check this by modification of the path in the installer process.

---

Further steps to handle the problem:

1. Uninstall your actual anaconda version.
2. Delete old Data found in:

   `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming`

   `C:\Users\YourUsername`

   - (In my case it was called `.anaconda` and `.conda` folder)
3. Restart PC
4. Install Anaconda as admin

Answer (score 0):

The followng command solved my issue.

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==228
```

Answer (score -1):

On windows 10, I faced the same error - only Anaconda Prompt was showing in the startup menu. What I did is i re-installed Anaconda  and selected **install for all users** of the pc (in my initial installation I have installed only for current user).

Answer (score -1):

What finally worked for me was:

1. Uninstalling Anaconda
2. Deleting all files that has "conda" in them - most of them should be
   located in: C:\Users\Admin
3. Delete especially the "condarc" file.
4. Reboot
5. Installed 32-bit installer (even though my system is 64-bit) and reboot

Finally worked. I have not yet re-tried with 64-bit installer, since I have a time critical project, but will do when again I have spare time.

P.S. what broke Anaconda for me was a blue screen I got while updating Anaconda. I guess it did not clear all old files and this broke the new installs.

Comment: I think the config file  `condarc` is the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I too faced a similar issue when  I was not able to find the Anaconda Navigator Desktop app in the start menu. But do not worry , Go to start Menu and Type Anaconda Navigator. Now within the apps menu you will find anaconda navigator with its icon. Click on that. After clicking you will find a command prompt dialog opened and a .exe file runs on your machine. Wait till it completes.

The Anaconda Navigator app opens on your machine.

Comment: OP has already stated that he is tried search in the start menu

Answer (score -2):

- From the Start menu select Anaconda Prompt.
  type `anaconda-navigator`.
- If Anaconda is installed properly, Anaconda Navigator will open.