# How to access Anaconda command prompt in Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: python, anaconda

I had to install the 64-bit version of Anaconda with python 3.5 in Windows 10. I followed the default settings (`AppData/Continuum/Anaconda3`). However, after installation, I am unsure how to access the Anaconda command prompt so that I can use conda to install packages. I also attempted to install Anaconda 64 bit in `C:/Program Files,` but several of the python script did not like the space and it failed to install.

What can I do to access the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: The conda tool is an executable. If you let the anaconda install change modify your paths, it's accessible in your console (cmd.exe).

Comment: Have you tried `anaconda -h` in PowerShell or Command Prompt?

Comment: Press Windows key, then search for Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: @sascha I didn't do that with the 32-bit installation, and an anaconda command prompt was created in my windows start menu. During the installation, the Anaconda options states that this is not recommended. If I modify the system paths, will conda know which installation of Anaconda to use?

Comment: @srig, both anaconda -h and searching for a 64-bit Anaconda Prompt failed.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) Specifically, `conda init` is the current recommendation.

Answer (score 55):

Go with the mouse to the Windows Icon (lower left) and start typing "Anaconda". There should show up some matching entries. Select "Anaconda Prompt". A new command window, named "Anaconda Prompt" will open. Now, you can work from there with Python, conda and other tools.

Comment: Only the 32-bit version of the anaconda prompt shows up.

Comment: Restarting? The cure-all thing for Windows.

Comment: Haha. You are right about restarting. Maybe it will show up at some point. As a workaround,  I can open a command prompt, cd to the Anaconda/scripts directory, and use conda. Then open spyder and use the installed packages. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: what is displayed as anaconda promt does not recognize "conda" as command

Answer (score 25):

### How to add Anaconda installation directory to your PATH variables

Adding Anaconda to your PATH variable will give you the ability to run a conda environment in any cmd or Powershell terminal window. Below are instructions on how to do that.

#### 1. open *environmental variables* window

Do this by either going to *my computer* and then right-clicking the background for the context menu > "properties". On the left side open "advanced system settings" or just search for "env..." in the start menu ([Win]+[s] keys).

Then click on *environment variables*

If you struggle with this step read [this explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).

#### 2. Edit Path in the *user environmental variables* section and add three new entries:

- `D:\path\to\anaconda3`
- `D:\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts`
- `D:\path\to\anaconda3\Library\bin`

`D:\path\to\anaconda3` should be the folder where you have installed anaconda

Click [OK] on all opened windows.

If you did everything correctly, you can test a `conda` command by opening a **new** powershell window.

```
conda --version
```

This should output something like: `conda 4.8.2`

Comment: Also, one can use cmd.exe after reproducing these two steps, and then open a cmd and write `conda init cmd.exe`. After hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and restarting the cmd, You can access all the conda environments.

Comment: "D:\path\to\anaconda3" how to find out this path?

Comment: @serge you can search for Anaconda Command Prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) > right click > Open file location > right click the shortcut> properties. The `Target` field should contain the path. The installation path is likely something like `C:\Users\Tobi\miniconda3` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\miniconda3`.

Answer (score 19):

To run Anaconda Prompt using an icon, I made an icon and put:

`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` (The file location would be different in each computer.)

at icon -> right click -> Property -> Shortcut -> Target

I see `%HOMEPATH%` at icon -> right click -> Property -> Start in

Test environment
   OS: Windows 10
   Library: Anaconda 10 (64 bit)

Answer (score 10):

I added "\Anaconda3_64\" and "\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\" to the PATH variable. Then I can use conda from powershell or command prompt.

Comment: You should add \Anaconda3\Library\bin too, otherwise pip and other libs will not work.

pip will fail with error: "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."

Answer (score 4):

If Anaconda Prompt is missing, you can create it by creating a shortcut file of Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and change its target to:

`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" <Anaconda Location>\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat`

Example:

`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\user_1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat`

Answer (score 0):

After installing Anaconda3 on your system you need to add Anaconda to the PATH environment variable. This will allow you to access Anaconda with the 'conda' command from cmd.exe or PowerShell.

The link I provided below go through the three major issues with not recognized error. Which are:

1. Environment PATH for Conda is not set
2. Environment PATH is incorrectly added
3. Anaconda version is older than the version of the Anaconda Navigator

LINK: https://appuals.com/fix-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/

My issue was resolved following the steps for issue #2 Environment PATH is incorrectly added. I did not have all three file paths in my variable environment.