# Can't perform basic commands in Anaconda Prompt? Something wrong with PATH?

Tags: python, import, path, anaconda, tweepy

When I try to perform basic commands such as 'from', 'import' or any others it just states that the command is not recognized as internal or external command. I've done some google-ing and it seems to be due to a messed up PATH.

can you see anything wrong with mine?

`C:\Users\Matthiascomp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Matthiascomp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Matthiascomp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\Python27`

I'm not sure where to look for fix.

Btw, the problem came up when I tried to import `tweepy`, which it refused to do because I got that same error message.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914980/how-to-access-anaconda-command-prompt-in-windows-10-64-bit

Comment: Did you start Python before you started trying to import?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and the problem is less likely in the path.

Actual problem resides in the fact that package tweepy is not installed correctly.

First try installing tweepy with the below method :

Step 1 : Click on `start`

Step 2 : Search and `Open Anaconda Navigator`

Step 3 : In the Anaconda Navigator, `Go to Evironments`

Step 4 : There is a drop down menu consisting of options : 1) Installed 2) Not Installed 3) Upgradable 4) Selected 5) All

Step 5 : Click on "Not Installed"

Step 6 : There is a block stating Search Packages, there enter the name of the package you want to install (like in your case it's tweepy).

Step 7 : Mark the name of the package to be installed in the search results, and click `Apply`

Installation will start.

Congratulations! You have successfully installed the package.

Now, try importing the package, it should work.