# Python is working in Anaconda prompt but not in command prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt

I have installed Anaconda and I have used it several time. However now I want to install Pyspark and it asked me to verify if I have coherent version of java and python installed on my computer. So, I used command prompt.
Unfortunately, everything is ok for java but for python: when I have written python --version it opened for me a new window to install python.

I can not understand how to handle the communication between Anaconda prompt and command prompt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Anaconda command prompt in Windows 10 (64-bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914980/how-to-access-anaconda-command-prompt-in-windows-10-64-bit)

It sounds like you don't have the relevant paths included in your PATH variable, and are unable to use Anaconda using the `conda` command from a standard cmd or PowerShell terminal. That said, I'd really recommend just using Anaconda prompt instead on Windows if you're able to, it'll probably save you some frustration in the future.

Comment: Can I use Pyspark with Anaconda prompt? Because all the examples I found said I need to use command prompt

Comment: From what I can gather yes, providing that you have the pre-requisite Spark jars and what not available in your environment.

Comment: and Java is accessible from anaconda?

Comment: Yep, Anaconda prompt/PowerShell-prompt are essentially wrappers for cmd and PowerShell respectively and have access to variables/config from each as a result. The main distinction is that the Anaconda prompts provide access to `conda` without having to add these to your system or user PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) Specifically, you need to run `conda init cmd.exe` *once*, then restart the shell.

Comment: In fact, with Anaconda everything works very well but I wonder why I can not see my anaconda environment with command prompt

Comment: @merv No it did not helped me because I am using windows

Comment: @baddy the Conda init answer includes both Windows and Unix instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading many answers I found this solution:

1- Create my env using the next instruction :

```
conda create -n Spark python=3.8 ipykernel jupyter anaconda
```

2- The second step was : activating my env using:

```
activate Spark
```

Here my env named Spark than after executing the last instruction I got this on my anconda prompt :

[image]

3- The 3rd step is to execute :

```
ipython kernel install --name Spark --user
```

In this case if I run python from my anconda prompt and execute :

```
import sys, os 
print(sys.executable)
```

And if I open the jupyter notebook and run :

```
import sys, os 
print(sys.executable)
```

I will find that I am using the same python.exe