# How to switch to Anaconda Prompt from CMD?

Tags: python

I know how to go to Anaconda Prompt by using Start-> Anaconda Prompt, I am wondering if I already in CMD under one specific folder, can I switch to Anaconda Prompt? The reason I asked is: typically, I go to one specific folder, then type cmd to open command windows, so the path is already on that folder. It is easier. If I go to start and anaconda prompt, then I have to type in cd c:/python/learning etc. in order to switch to the folder path manually. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is already answered here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914980/how-to-access-anaconda-command-prompt-in-windows-10-64-bit#:%7E:text=Go%20with%20the%20mouse%20to,%22Anaconda%20Prompt%22%20will%20open.).
In your start menu type Anaconda Prompt you will find similar applications named Anaconda .

Comment: Thanks Eng.Hassan Ibraheem, I still not sure. I did add it to PATH, and when I type conda activate enviromentname, it told me that  "Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'" , how do i do next? Thanks

Comment: You should configure your windows path configurations before using Anaconda follow this tutorial https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows