# How to start anaconda navigator in windows

Tags: anaconda

I've just installed the latest version of Anaconda "Anaconda 5.0.1 For Windows Installer" on windows but can't find the Anaconda Navigator on the search menu. Plus when i tried to run the command conda It's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda Installed but Cannot Launch Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841470/anaconda-installed-but-cannot-launch-navigator)