# activate.bat is not recognized as internal external command

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm a beginner in machine learning so tried installing ANACONDA after the complete installation as the tutorial shows it doesn't ask me to install VS code.
That's not issue I can download it separately but I cant find the anaconda navigator.
when I open the anaconda prompt it shows activate.bat is not recognized as internal external command can you please help me if you know what is the problem.

I'm struggling in this issue from past 3 days... reinstalled countless time. Tried installing miniconda.
After installing still navigator doesn't appear. 
But Promt works fine here so can run commands to install the navigator.
When the navigator gets installed I cant launch any apps like Jupyter notebook or spyder.

It shows Spyder Crashed.

Any help is appreciated.

Procedure that I followed.

1) Installed Anaconda

2) I did not find Navigator nor did the anaconda promt start it shows activate.bat is not recognized as internal external command.

3) So uninstalled anaconda and installed Miniconda in this anaconda prompt works fine but navigator wasnt there so i followed this post
[Anaconda Installed but Cannot Launch Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841470/anaconda-installed-but-cannot-launch-navigator)

4) Then I could use the navigator and while I try to launch the spyder or the jupyter it throws error saying spyder crashed during last session

Can anyone help?