# Cannot launch anaconda navigator

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have successfully downloaded the latest version of Anaconda. In the start menu, all the apps are showing but only anaconda prompt and Powershell is opening not other like navigator, jupyter, etc. I have restarted the system and also cleared all the env paths. still, it is not opening. Pls, help.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55661947/11667949

Comment: no, it isn't. all the things I got on SO I tried, but it failed. I've started using G-colab.

Comment: How did you install Anaconda? Can you launch the apps from the command line? _and also cleared all the env paths_ What do you mean?

Comment: yes, i did clear the paths. Although I left trying it I'm using colab instead.