# Anaconda: 'Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python

I install anaconda2 in windows7. When I type `python` in windows cmd prompt, it gives the error:

```
'Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

It is fine to type `python` in anaconda prompt.

The installation path for anaconda is:

```
C:\Users\Fruitlab_07\Anaconda2
```

I try to add the path to `Path` variable by typing in cmd:

```
set %path%; C:\Users\Fruitlab_07\Anaconda2
```

But the prompt shows the path not defined

Comment: Spelling and (non-)capitalization matter. You'll need to be meticulous about such things if you want to get anywhere in computer programming.

Comment: The spelling isn't the issue here I don't think. The OP just messed it up in the question. This is likely a path issue. @jingweimo Do you have the python.exe in your windows path? This lets the command prompt know what program to use when you type python.

Comment: @dustyjuicebox: The python.exe in the anaconda folder. Do I need to add it in Path? But it seems that anaconda advises not to do that.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030373/anaconda-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: That question seems to confirm you SHOULD add it to the path. You need to find the python.exe under the "\..\anaconda\" folder and add it to the path. The " 'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command" almost always points to a path error if you know you ran the installer for whatever software you're working on. I am not fully sure why anaconda says to not add it to path. Maybe to prevent conflicts with possible existing python paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with anaconda but I'm certain it's not an actual problem with you're installation as, in order to use the C# compiler, (csc filename) you have to execute developer command prompt from a bash file. Perhaps, just as with c#, installing anaconda2 doesn't install any commands to Window's command prompt.

I don't know of any API/compiler installers that do install commands to the base command prompt other than java so I can't say whether or not anaconda should. In the meantime, have you made sure the command isn't 'python' instead of 'Python'?