# Installing python packages from cmd in windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I recently downloaded anaconda and added it to the environment variables following the question below:
[anaconda - path environment variable in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030373/anaconda-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

I added it as

```
C:\Users\My_User\Anaconda3
```

The thing is, I've been trying to install some packages using either pip or conda without luck.

For instance:

```
pip install seaborn
```

Return the following

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImrdU.png)

Does somebody know how can I enable package installation either through pip or conda?

I'm very new to executing commands through cmd and couldn't figure out a better way to type my question, sorry about that

Comment: Please do not put code or terminal input/output into images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: Please consider reading through [the Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/). It is a much better resource than following (often outdated) suggestions from StackOverflow answers. Everything you are asking is clearly covered. Also, be aware that you shouldn't be installing packages through `pip` if they are available through `conda` (see ["Using `pip` in a Conda environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)).

Comment: @darthbith, sorry !
Wasn't aware of that

Comment: @LucasAbreu You can [edit] your post to put the content from the image into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
python -m pip install seaborn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Could you tell me what does the "-m" mean, please?

Comment: The real key here is that the python interpreter is directly invoked, rather than counting on "pip" to be recognized as a python script and invoking it indirectly.

The "-m" means the operand immediately following is a module to be run as a script; really "python -m pip" and "python pip" are equivalent; but the important part that -m provides is that any operands after the module name are recognized as parameters to the module rather than as parameters to the interpreter.

Comment: While this technically overcomes the immediate issue, I'm downvoting because this promotes a discouraged practice that can lead to an unstable Conda env. Conda users should only resort to `pip` if the package is unavailable through `conda` (see ["Using `pip` in a Conda environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Open Anaconda Navigator
[navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh2rJ.png)

Step 2:
Go to Environments and select All packages, to view the list of all packages installed.
[environment packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpAYP.png)

Step 3:
Look for seaborn in the Search bar
[search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frjab.png)

Install it and see if that works.

If it doesn't then try creating a new environment and installing the seaborn package there. [create new environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0GK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're running `pip` from inside of the Python interpreter when you should be running it from the command line. To exit the Python interpreter, press `ctrl+d`. Then, make sure you have `pip` installed and in your PATH and you can try again.