# No module named 'pandas' in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on python programming, I can see the below error even I installed a library 'pandas' using 'pip install pandas'

```
import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Note : I have already set my environment variable to

```
"C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts"
```

I am not sure, what I am missing to set, could someone help me?

Comment: see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Anaconda and set path accordingly.

Comment: I have to install anaconda, so that I can code  "Visual studio code"?. I am new to python. Please help me

Comment: Try run "conda" in terminal, if it gives the error that's mean you have path issue, for solving the path issue you can visit here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030373/anaconda-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: I have installed anaconda and tried ->'Conda is not recognized in Vs code terminal'

Comment: It's a path issue. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030373/anaconda-path-environment-variable-in-windows